# Class with adding object with limited number until full

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am trying to create a class that can add different combinations up to 10 as I add. What I am struggling with is the adding of the different combinations into a variable that I can query. Here is the current code I have:

```
class Plugboard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__head = 0
    
    def add(self, item):
        __head = 0
        if __head >= 10:
            leads = item.append()
            __head += 1
        return leads
```

The information I add as an input is the following:

```
plugboard = Plugboard()
plugboard.add("SZ")
plugboard.add("AG")
plugboard.add("CD")
```

And would like to query the variable to see what the different plugboard combinations are. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need use `self.leads`, not `leads`.

code:

```
class Plugboard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__head = 0
        self.leads = []
    
    def add(self, item):
        if self.__head >= 10:
            print("leads already got 10 items")
        elif item in self.leads:
            print(f"leads already have this item: {item}")
        else:
            self.leads.append(item)
            self.__head += 1
        return self.leads

plugboard = Plugboard()
print(plugboard.add("SZ"))
print(plugboard.add("AG"))
print(plugboard.add("CD"))

print(plugboard.add("CD"))

print(plugboard.add("4"))
print(plugboard.add("5"))
print(plugboard.add("6"))
print(plugboard.add("7"))
print(plugboard.add("8"))
print(plugboard.add("9"))
print(plugboard.add("10"))

print(plugboard.add("11"))
```

result:

```
['SZ']
['SZ', 'AG']
['SZ', 'AG', 'CD']
leads already have this item: CD
['SZ', 'AG', 'CD']
['SZ', 'AG', 'CD', '4']
['SZ', 'AG', 'CD', '4', '5']
['SZ', 'AG', 'CD', '4', '5', '6']
['SZ', 'AG', 'CD', '4', '5', '6', '7']
['SZ', 'AG', 'CD', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
['SZ', 'AG', 'CD', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['SZ', 'AG', 'CD', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
leads already got 10 items
['SZ', 'AG', 'CD', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```